# Send SMS in Ionic 2 without using Cordova Plugins

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic2, sms

Good Day, I want to automatically sned an SMS without using the Cordova SMS plugin. I want to send the verification code to every customer after they sign up to the app. Is there any possible way to do it? Hope you can help me. Thank you in advance. I am using Ionic 2.

Comment: Is there any way I can use plugin without opening the messaging app(automatically send the SMS).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backend running it's quite easy. This example uses Node with the [Nexmo SMS API](https://developer.nexmo.com/messaging/sms/overview).

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.body);
  const toNumber = req.body.number;
  const text = req.body.text;
  nexmo.message.sendSms(
    NUMBER, toNumber, text, {type: 'unicode'},
    (err, responseData) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.dir(responseData);
      }
    }
  );
 });
```

See [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/send-sms-from-the-browser-with-web-apis-node-and-nexmo) for a full example.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use it in Ionic 2?

Comment: @Patrick Run a Node server with this code and do an Ajax api call (POST) to the server to make it send the sms. Try these articles: [Send SMS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/send-sms-from-the-browser-with-web-apis-node-and-nexmo), [async API calls](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-axios-166cb0035237)